# Wordpress site isn't displaying the wysiwyg editor content?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

My Wordpress website really isn't working to how I want?!

It was working fine, with nothing being touched, Then lately I find every-page is displaying the same content on each page. Not the individual content that is in the wysiwyg editor.

This is doing my head in, I have a modified theme in which I have already replaced with the original theme files, page.php, index.php and single.php to see if it is a problem with them pages. But it is not!?

The link is http://www.alleanza.co.uk and I was suppose to hand it over last weds and I still can't because no content is being pulled through. Does anyone have any ideas that may help?

However I have noticed that it is pulling information from the Hello World Post instead of the page's wysiwyg content.

However, here is the content for page.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Normal Template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content">
    <div id="greybread"><?php if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs(); ?></div>

<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


    <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
    </div></div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Go ask here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it has changed as I have found out more it is not directly the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the code you have in your page.php, inside the loop?

If it is missing the `<php the_content(); ?>` tag within the loop, you will not see content loading from Wordpress dashboard. It might also be because you have selected the non-default template for your page from the page attributed module.

Comment: well I have a little bit of help.

http://alleanza.co.uk/1/hello-world/ - it is displaying Hello World post instead of the page content.

P.S I'll update page.php info now.

Comment: A post's template file is single.php, a page's default template file is page.php. If it is displaying wrong content, make sure the_content(); tag exists inside the loop in both the template files, and there isn't some hard-coding done. Also make sure the query is the default query, if a specific page or category is being queried, it will load content from that page/category, and not the current post. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage

Comment: Nope it wouldn't, I just meant to clarify cause you said the content was loading hello world post. If a page is loading another post, it might be a category archive page, in which case it's default template file is archive.php, or its default query has been modified outside the loop (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage)

Answer (score 0):

Notice you have specified a template name in your page.php (Template Name: Normal Template). This means this is not the default template any longer. If you want to make it default template for all pages, remove the lines before the get_header() tag. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#What_Template_is_used_to_Display_a_Particular_Page.3F)

Or you can select the 'Normal template' as the page template under page attributed on the Edit page. See below:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-attributes/#template